Matplotlib weird behaviour when plotting a timeline with plt.barh
I have a DataFrame of events. I want to plot these events to show the timeline for a day.
event_start     event_end   event_type
0   2024-09-12 21:59:00     2024-09-13 05:09:00     Stop
1   2024-09-13 01:26:00     2024-09-13 02:00:00     Farming
2   2024-09-13 02:00:00     2024-09-13 02:35:00     Active
3   2024-09-13 02:35:00     2024-09-13 06:11:00     Farming
4   2024-09-13 02:35:00     2024-09-13 06:11:00     Farming
5   2024-09-13 06:11:00     2024-09-13 07:27:00     Active
6   2024-09-13 07:27:00     2024-09-13 07:47:00     Stop
7   2024-09-13 07:47:00     2024-09-13 08:00:00     Active
8   2024-09-13 08:00:00     2024-09-13 08:06:00     Stop
9   2024-09-13 08:06:00     2024-09-13 08:07:00     Active
10  2024-09-13 08:07:00     2024-09-13 08:16:00     Stop
11  2024-09-13 08:16:00     2024-09-13 08:18:00     Active
12  2024-09-13 08:18:00     2024-09-13 08:45:00     Stop
13  2024-09-13 08:45:00     2024-09-13 09:00:00     Active
14  2024-09-13 09:00:00     2024-09-13 09:31:00     Stop
15  2024-09-13 09:31:00     2024-09-13 10:24:00     Active
16  2024-09-13 10:24:00     2024-09-13 10:32:00     Stop
17  2024-09-13 10:32:00     2024-09-13 10:37:00     Active
18  2024-09-13 10:37:00     2024-09-13 16:29:00     Stop
19  2024-09-13 16:29:00     2024-09-13 16:34:00     Active

I tried plotting with matplotlib.pyplot.barh, but the last event, starting from 16:29 and ending at 16:34 (Active) is getting plotted as a block from 16:39 to roughly 18:30. I can't understand why.
This is the plot_timeline function that I'm using.
def plot_timeline(events):
    df_events = events

    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

    for _, row in df_events.iterrows():
        color_map = {
            'Active': 'lightblue',
            'Idling': 'red',
            'Stop': 'black',
            'Farming': 'green'
        }
        print(f"start : {row['event_start']}, end : {row['event_end']}, type : {row['event_type']}")
        plt.barh(y=0, width=(row['event_end'] - row['event_start']).total_seconds() / 3600, 
                 left=row['event_start'], 
                 color=color_map.get(row['event_type'], 'lightblue'))

    plt.xlim(pd.to_datetime(f"{df_events['event_start'].dt.date.iloc[-1]} 04:00"),
             pd.to_datetime(f"{df_events['event_start'].dt.date.iloc[-1]} 23:00"))

    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=1))
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))

    plt.title('Timeline of Events')
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.yticks([])  
    plt.grid(axis='x', linestyle='--', alpha=0.7)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
plot_timeline(events)


(EDIT) : print output
start : 2024-09-12 21:59:00, end : 2024-09-13 05:09:00, type : Stop
start : 2024-09-13 01:26:00, end : 2024-09-13 02:00:00, type : Farming
start : 2024-09-13 02:00:00, end : 2024-09-13 02:35:00, type : Active
start : 2024-09-13 02:35:00, end : 2024-09-13 06:11:00, type : Farming
start : 2024-09-13 02:35:00, end : 2024-09-13 06:11:00, type : Farming
start : 2024-09-13 06:11:00, end : 2024-09-13 07:27:00, type : Active
start : 2024-09-13 07:27:00, end : 2024-09-13 07:47:00, type : Stop
start : 2024-09-13 07:47:00, end : 2024-09-13 08:00:00, type : Active
start : 2024-09-13 08:00:00, end : 2024-09-13 08:06:00, type : Stop
start : 2024-09-13 08:06:00, end : 2024-09-13 08:07:00, type : Active
start : 2024-09-13 08:07:00, end : 2024-09-13 08:16:00, type : Stop
start : 2024-09-13 08:16:00, end : 2024-09-13 08:18:00, type : Active
start : 2024-09-13 08:18:00, end : 2024-09-13 08:45:00, type : Stop
start : 2024-09-13 08:45:00, end : 2024-09-13 09:00:00, type : Active
start : 2024-09-13 09:00:00, end : 2024-09-13 09:31:00, type : Stop
start : 2024-09-13 09:31:00, end : 2024-09-13 10:24:00, type : Active
start : 2024-09-13 10:24:00, end : 2024-09-13 10:32:00, type : Stop
start : 2024-09-13 10:32:00, end : 2024-09-13 10:37:00, type : Active
start : 2024-09-13 10:37:00, end : 2024-09-13 16:29:00, type : Stop
start : 2024-09-13 16:29:00, end : 2024-09-13 16:34:00, type : Active


For your own debugging purposes, I'd recommend printing out the contents of row during the for loop, so you (and we) can see what each row contains as it progresses.

color_map.get(row['event_type'], 'lightblue') is setting the default colour to light blue. I wonder if some extra event is being added after the last event you have there? Maybe change that default value to something other than your active colour, to see if this is the case

Yes, could it be that the final couple of event types have some trailing whitespace?

hi @tmdavison, i changed it to 'gray', and I'm still getting the same plot


It seems that using Rectangles turns out to be easier.
The first part is devoted to have a-sort-of-data-frame and it's unimportant, the function put_r is a bit more interesting.
Note also that adding rectangles to a plot doesn't change the axis limits, but you already use plt.xlim()...
Eventually I plotted a few scatter points to have the possibility of drawing a legend.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

data = ''''\
0   2024-09-12 21:59:00     2024-09-13 05:09:00     Stop
1   2024-09-13 01:26:00     2024-09-13 02:00:00     Farming
2   2024-09-13 02:00:00     2024-09-13 02:35:00     Active
3   2024-09-13 02:35:00     2024-09-13 06:11:00     Farming
4   2024-09-13 02:35:00     2024-09-13 06:11:00     Farming
5   2024-09-13 06:11:00     2024-09-13 07:27:00     Active
6   2024-09-13 07:27:00     2024-09-13 07:47:00     Stop
7   2024-09-13 07:47:00     2024-09-13 08:00:00     Active
8   2024-09-13 08:00:00     2024-09-13 08:06:00     Stop
9   2024-09-13 08:06:00     2024-09-13 08:07:00     Active
10  2024-09-13 08:07:00     2024-09-13 08:16:00     Stop
11  2024-09-13 08:16:00     2024-09-13 08:18:00     Active
12  2024-09-13 08:18:00     2024-09-13 08:45:00     Stop
13  2024-09-13 08:45:00     2024-09-13 09:00:00     Active
14  2024-09-13 09:00:00     2024-09-13 09:31:00     Stop
15  2024-09-13 09:31:00     2024-09-13 10:24:00     Active
16  2024-09-13 10:24:00     2024-09-13 10:32:00     Stop
17  2024-09-13 10:32:00     2024-09-13 10:37:00     Active
18  2024-09-13 10:37:00     2024-09-13 16:29:00     Stop
19  2024-09-13 16:29:00     2024-09-13 16:34:00     Active'''
data = dict(zip(
    'index start_day start_time end_day end_time type'.split(),
    zip(*[l.split() for l in data.split('\n')])
))
data['start'] = [datetime.fromisoformat(dt) for dt in (' '.join(t) for t in zip(data['start_day'], data['start_time']))]
data['end'] = [datetime.fromisoformat(dt) for dt in (' '.join(t) for t in zip(data['end_day'], data['end_time']))]

color = {'Active':  'lightblue',
         'Idling':  'red',
         'Stop':    'lightgrey',
         'Farming': 'green'}

def put_r(d1, d2, color):
    plt.gca().add_patch(
        Rectangle((d1, 0), d2-d1, 1,
                  linewidth=0.5, edgecolor='k',
                  facecolor=color, alpha=0.8))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11,4), layout='constrained', edgecolor='k')
plt.xlim(datetime(2024, 9, 13, 4), datetime(2024, 9, 13, 23))
for d1, d2, t in zip(*[data[s] for s in 'start end type'.split()]):
    print(d1, d2, t.rjust(8), color[t])
    put_r(d1, d2, color[t])

for t, c in color.items():
    ax.scatter(datetime(2024, 9, 13, 4)-timedelta(minutes=1), 0, color=c, label=t)

plt.title('Timeline of Events')

plt.xlabel('Time')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.HourLocator(interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))

ax.set_yticks([])
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
plt.legend()
plt.show()


thanks for the alternative, though I eventually switched to plotly's timeline function.
